# Updating From Windows 8.1 to 10 without losing data

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-update

I'm going to update my Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

My Question is, will I lose my data on the C drive? That's where Windows 8.1 is.

If so, is there any way to save my data from being lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the data are not lost. But it is always recommend to make a full system image of the drive, before doing an OS upgrade. There are a lot of tool like [macrium reflect free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) which can make a full system image.

Comment: Ok i will try that , by the way thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

in a normal upgrade, your files, drivers, and even programs/apps survive, and is ready for use immediately after updating. I have not lost anything on my machines.

Comment: Yes @Tore i was also confuse about my apps and drivers etc.